# Is it possible to install Landscape openstack in virtual machine?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cloud, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I tried to install ubuntu landscape openstack in virtual machine for test purposes and to undrestand how does it work, but it does not work.

I followed the official ubuntu tutorial
[Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Download | Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)

Firstly, i choosed the Landscape option, I waited for 3 hours and it was blocked in "Creating KVM for juju state server" step. So i cancelled the installation and relaunched a new install but i choosed option "Single" instead of landscape.

With single option, it was blocked in "Initializing Environnement" step.

[image]

What's wrong in what i did ?

I use Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed you are using Virtualbox for your tests and unfortunately I can't comment to the success of using that software for testing the Openstack installer. However, you could accomplish this easily with `virt-manager` and KVM.

With that said, the installer uses a combination of KVM/LXC when doing its deployment. If running this within an existing virtual environment you'll want to make sure nested KVM is enabled:

```
 $ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
```

If not you can enable with

```
 $ echo “options kvm-intel nested=1″ | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/kvm-intel.conf
```

This is assuming you have Intel/VMX but the same can be accomplished with AMD/SVM (though I've not tested this thoroughly).

If you need further assistance please come chat with us at **#ubuntu-solutions** on *irc.freenode.net*.

Answer (score 4):

VirtualBox does not pass VT-X/AMD-V to the guest operating system, hence [KVM cannot work inside VirtualBox](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589).